# Gradle: where are task dependencies defined for distZip task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I am using the [gradle application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

I noticed that:

1. distZip task get's run before the assemble task.
2. And I can see
   from the docs (link above), and confirmed during my gradle run, that
   the distZip tasks depends on: jar, startScripts tasks

So execution looks something like this:

```
> Task :my-app:processResources
> Task :my-app:compileJava
> Task :my-app:classes
> Task :my-app:jar
> Task :my-app:startScripts
> Task :my-app:distTar
> Task :my-app:distZip
> Task :my-app:assemble
```

Looking through the code in [ApplicationPlugin.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.java) and/or [DistributionPlugin.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/distribution/plugins/DistributionPlugin.java), I expected to see the task dependencies defined. 
 e.g. something like this:

```
distZipTask.dependsOn(jarTask)
distZipTask.dependsOn(createScriptsTask)
assembleTask.dependsOn(distZipTask)
```

...but I couldn't find anything like this in the java code.

Would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of where to look to find out how these tasks are 'linked'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle can determine implicit task dependencies from task inputs. If (the output of) a task is used as input of another task, Gradle can derive that there must be a dependency on the task. This functionality is called [**incremental build support**](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-incremental-build-support), as it also supports checking for changes in the inputs or outputs to skip tasks if the inputs did not change.

Regarding your example, the task dependencies are defined implicitly in [line 197](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.java#L197) and [line 208](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.java#L208) of the file `ApplicationPlugin.java`:

```
libChildSpec.from(jar);
...
binChildSpec.from(startScripts);
```

The arguments in these lines are the respective tasks (to be exact: providers of the tasks). The `from` method can often be used to define sources of a file operation (e.g. copying, zipping ...). So we define the results (outputs) of the tasks `jar` and `startScripts` as a source of some operation (`CopySpec`). The resulting `CopySpec` objects are then passed to both tasks `distZip` and `distTar`. When a task tries to resolve the defined sources it finds the tasks `jar` and `startScripts` and defines the dependencies on them on its own.

Please note that the mentioned task `assemble` is a so-called *lifecycle task*. It does not run any action but can be used to organize tasks into build phases (just like `build` and `check`).

Comment: Thanks very much Lukas.  That answers a number of questions I was wondering about.